# Exception when maximizing MPart

Tags: exception, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm creating perspectives in my Eclipse application. Now For working with my perspectives I created some shared elements to share between different perspectives. One of them is a MPartStack with some dynamic MPart elements in it.

When I double click on a MPart that is in the MPartStack I got some strange error related to the MinMax addon. But I want to have the min max behavior in my application. All the MParts that are in the share MPartStack has this problem. Other MParts that are in normal MPartStacks I can minimize and maximize without any problem (only the shared MPartStack will not be minimized).

Someone any idea how to fix this issue so that my users can normally minimize and maximize stacks?

My full stack trace:

```
   !MESSAGE Exception while dispatching event org.osgi.service.event.Event [topic=org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/ApplicationElement/tags/ADD] {ChangedElement=org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.PartStackImpl@69f69078 (elementId: partstack.shared, tags: [NoAutoCollapse, active, Maximized], contributorURI: platform:/plugin/CR-IT_client) (widget: CTabFolder {}, renderer: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer@52963839, toBeRendered: true, onTop: false, visible: true, containerData: null, accessibilityPhrase: null), org.eclipse.e4.data={ChangedElement=org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.PartStackImpl@69f69078 (elementId: partstack.shared, tags: [NoAutoCollapse, active, Maximized], contributorURI: platform:/plugin/CR-IT_client) (widget: CTabFolder {}, renderer: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer@52963839, toBeRendered: true, onTop: false, visible: true, containerData: null, accessibilityPhrase: null), AttName=tags, EventType=ADD, Position=2, Widget=CTabFolder {}, NewValue=Maximized}, AttName=tags, EventType=ADD, Position=2, Widget=CTabFolder {}, NewValue=Maximized} to handler org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.di.UIEventObjectSupplier$UIEventHandler@1c512bb
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.di.UIEventObjectSupplier$UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventObjectSupplier.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4813)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.di.UIEventObjectSupplier$UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventObjectSupplier.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EcoreEList.dispatchNotification(EcoreEList.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.NotifyingListImpl.addUnique(NotifyingListImpl.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.AbstractEList.add(AbstractEList.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.minmax.MinMaxAddon.setState(MinMaxAddon.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.minmax.MinMaxAddon.access$1(MinMaxAddon.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.minmax.MinMaxAddon$2.mouseDoubleClick(MinMaxAddon.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4410)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4228)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3816)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.findElementsRecursive(ModelServiceImpl.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.findElements(ModelServiceImpl.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.findElements(ModelServiceImpl.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.getActivePerspective(ModelServiceImpl.java:959)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.minmax.MinMaxAddon.getElementsToMinimize(MinMaxAddon.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.minmax.MinMaxAddon.maximize(MinMaxAddon.java:655)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.minmax.MinMaxAddon.subscribeTopicTagsChanged(MinMaxAddon.java:363)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    ... 46 more
```

Comment: MinMaxAddon is failing to find the parent window for whatever it has been told to maximize. This is causing the model service to get upset. It is doing the maximize because a UI element's tags have been changed to specify maximized. You will have to debug the addon to work out why it doesn't have a proper parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was identical to an known issue in Eclispe RCP.

They suggested to use a MArea -> MPartStack structure as a shared element instead of only a MPartStack. Directly use Part Stack is not a good idea and contains some errors.